# Отправка цели в яндекс метрику при нажатии в стороннем виджете

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-метрика

На сайт повесил виджет колбека. Он не интегрирован с метрикой. Задача: при отправке колбека (пользователь ввел телефон и нажал кнопку) сторонний скрипт отсылает цель в метрику. Сам код виджета мы редактировать не можем, что бы вставить туда отправку цели в метрику. Но можно же написать отдельный код, который будет ловить нажатие на кнопку внутри виджета (в моем случае на "lptrack_banner-button") и в этот момент отправлять цель в метрику.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов масса, если вы используете jQuery, вам может помочь следующее:

```
$(document).on('mousedown','.lptrack_banner-button',function(e){
   // metrika events here
   return true;
});
```

Я намеренно не использую клик, тк есть вероятность конфликта с внутренними событиями колбека.

Comment: Не получается. можно на моем примере? Страница pololacoste.ru/catalog/item/243 пробую вот так (код ниже счетчика меткики и колбека:  <script type="text/javascript">$(document).on('mousedown','.lptrack-ph-img-circle',function(e){yaCounter23737942.reachGoal('email_order'); return true;}); 
</script>

Comment: У вас очень низкая версия jQuery 1.4.4. Текущая версия 3+. Вам поможет `on` заменить на `bind`. Начало будет выглядеть так: `$(document).bind('mousedown' ...`

Comment: Спасибо! Начало работать с bind. Но! 1) Код почему то  реагирует не на нажатие кнопки .lptrack_banner-button а на нажатие любой части формы ввода телефона. Например человек открыл форму, ничего не вводил и нажал крестик на форме (закрыл). Цель засчитали выполненной. Как сделать что бы реагировало только на нажатие .lptrack_banner-button  ?   2)Пробовал сделать другую цель на вызов формы колбека (нажатие на .lptrack-ph-img-circle )  Почему то цель не засчитывается. Может знаете почему?